# Equilvalent spy software/apps for windows phone (8.1) Nokia

Tags: lumia-925

Is there any spy software/apps that work with a WindosPhones (8.1) that are equivalent to the Dr. Fone program?  Wanting to retrieve/monitor text messages of teenager.

Answer (score 2):

Third party apps do not have the capability to read SMS/MMS messages on the Windows Phone platform.